# I want to stop a activity after the animation loop gets completed

Tags: android, gif

There is a button in my app, after i click on the button another activity starts in which the animation i.e. the gif file is being played. The gif file is of single loop. All i want to do is after one loop of the animation gets completed, the current activity should automatically return to the previous (first) activity. The animation time can be taken into consideration while doing this. Please help.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

boolean gif;
long time = 8000;
Handler handler;
GIFWebView view;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (gif){

    }
    else
    {


    GIFWebView view = new GIFWebView
            (this, "file:///android_asset/imageedit_ball.gif");

    gif = true;

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            gif = false;
        }
    }, time);
    setContentView(view);
    }
}
}
```

This is the code for it.

Comment: Add `finish();` at the end of the loop.

Comment: it isn't working after the loop. can you please tell me where should i add finish exactly.

Comment: Add this inside `run()`  `gif = false; finish();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `finish()` in  the `run()` method on the handler.

Your code will still not behave as expected because the handler with `postDelayed` is not executed *exactly* at the time you specify. It will be a few milliseconds off. This is not important when the animation takes several seconds but will be noticeable for very short animations.